# Change behaviour of Date at 00:00

Tags: 7, datetime

Is there a way to change how Date works when saving dates with the time in 00:00:00? I have a calendar view, and I would like to avoid having events showing as all-day when the are saved with a time of 00:00. Is this possible? I have a content type that cousd either start at 00:00 or end at 00:00, but those are not all day events.

Answer (score 0):

You could (a) try changing the granularity of the date field in your content type (b) override the theme function. ([ref](http://yogesh1110.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/how-can-i-remove-all-day-text-that-is.html))